# D - static if on variadic arguments not working properly

Tags: d

Suppose I have the following variadic function, which job is to concat together a path from pieces (each piece can either be an index of integral type, or a node of string type):

```
string 
makePath(P...)(P path)
{
    import std.conv;
    import std.format;

    string res;
    foreach (piece; path) {
        pragma(msg, typeof(piece).stringof);
        static if (is(piece: size_t))
            res = res is null ? piece.to!string : format("%s[%s]", res, piece);
        else if (is(piece: string))
            res = res is null ? piece : format("%s.%s", res, piece);
        else
            static assert(0);
    }
}
```

If I later use it like this: `string path = makePath("foo", "bar")`, somehow the code reaches the `static assert(0);` and the compilation terminates. This is most curious, but the pragma actually writes `string` as the type of the first argument despite the fact that a code path for some other type was taken.

Even better, using `makePath(12, 13)` results in the compiler complaining about *both* the line for *strings* (about incompatible types of `int` and `string`) and `static assert`. What is going on here?

I've tried this both on DMD and LDC.

Comment: The first `else if` should prolly be `else static if`. Is that a mistake in your original code or just here?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Yes, this is a mistake in the original code (a really stupid one now that you've pointed that out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is` keyword is what's at fault here. (It's quite a confusing keyword I find...)

I'd recommend you use the templates in std.traits to test for types, most there are covered: https://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html

Here's a working version of your function:

```
string 
makePath(P...)(P path)
{
    import std.conv;
    import std.format;
    import std.traits : isSomeString, isNumeric;

    string res;
    foreach (piece; path) {
        static if (isNumeric!(typeof(piece)))
            res = res is null ? piece.to!string : format("%s[%s]", res, piece);
        else static if (isSomeString!(typeof(piece))) // Note, you were missing the 'static' on the 'else if' part
            res = res is null ? piece : format("%s.%s", res, piece);
        else
            static assert(0);
    }
    return res;
}

unittest {
    static assert(makePath("foo","bar") == "foo.bar");
    static assert(makePath("foo","bar",1) == "foo.bar[1]");
}
```